# How to Generate Edifact message from a xml?

Tags: java, xml, api, converters, edifact

I'm currently dealing with customs messages Beans in Java.
After filling in the Beans with different values, I want to produce an EDIFACT CUSDEC message corresponding to each message.

For each attribute of a message Bean, I have the information to put the attribute in the right place in EDIFACT CUSEDC format.

Thus, I am looking for a free tool (a Java API) which could ideally convert my full-filled Bean into an EDIFACT CUSDEC message.

I found a commercial solution (not free) there :

http://www.datadirect.com/products/edifact-grid/index.ssp

And a quick tutorial here :

http://biemond.blogspot.com/2008/09/generate-edifact-message-from-xml.html

But ... unfortunately it is not free..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A pure EDIFACT serializer is easy to build; did so myself. The work is in the mapping of your-bean to the edifact format, UNH, S01 and stuff like that. Do you already have that mapping handy, or should the tool also do mapping?

Comment: For each attribute of my Bean I have the following mapping information i.e. the segment that must contain the attribute, the "+" level of the attribute, the ":" level of the attribute. So the tool must be able to use these information to put attribute in the right position in the EDIFACT message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note that the only solution I found is to implement my own mapping engine.

This is made by having :

- an xml representation of an edifact message
- an XPath mapping path attached to each of the bean attributes and mapping them to the xml representation of EDIFACT

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a closer look at [Smooks Website](http://www.smooks.org/)

It offers various mappings, e.g.:

```
Java -> EDI
EDI -> Java
XML -> Java
Java -> XML
...
```

For the different UN/EDIFACT directories it offers mapping functionality out of the box. I suggest that you examine the examples and the documentation on the Smooks website.

Answer (score 1):

try http://bots.sourceforge.net
it already has a mapping engine.

Comment: That seems to be a good one too ! Thanks eppye, I'll investigate this tool.